# jQuery-mobile-iscrollview not scrolling when changing contents style display:none to display:block OR jquery show and hide

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins

I am using jQuery-mobile-iscrollview from :https://github.com/watusi/jquery-mobile-iscrollview, but this is not working when changing content styles (display:none to display:block) under scrollview content.

This is my code:

```
$(".collapse_btn").on('tap',function(){
    $(this).siblings().toggle();
});
```

This is My HTML Code:

```
<div class="collapsible_step_two">
 <div class="collapse_content_step_two">
  <div class="ui-grid-a">
   <div class="ui-block-a">
    <button data-role="none" class="collapsecontent_btn">Whats Included ?</button>
   </div>
   <div class="ui-block-b" style="text-align:right;">
    <button data-role="none" class="collapsecontent_btn">Information</button>
   </div>                
  </div>
 </div>
 <button data-role="none" class="collapse_btn"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Try change display to `inline-block`, using `.css('display', 'inline-block')`.

Comment: Thank you.. Omar for your replay. i am tried this but not working...

Comment: Can you show the html code of what you're tying to show/hide?

Comment: Hi. Omar, can you check my HTML Code?

Comment: Are you trying to show buttons?

Comment: Yes Omar, I need show this two buttons...

Comment: Change them to `data-role=button` and try again

Comment: I am trying to create custom button style.....

Comment: can you post your custom css?

Comment: Hi Omar, I got the solution: 

My code here:

$(this).siblings().toggle().trigger("updatelayout");

Comment: great, add it as an answer quickly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i got this solution:

```
$(this).siblings().toggle().trigger("updatelayout");
```

Comment: Oh.. You saved lot of time of mine :)